# How to reorder the way VoiceOver reads NSTextField's on a NSTableCellView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility, nstableview, voiceover

I have a single-column `NSTableView`, populated with custom `NSTableCellView`'s, very similar to the standard Mail app of macOS. Each custom `NSTableCellView` has four non-selectable read-only `NSTextField`'s. VoiceOver for Accessibility reads things left to right, top to bottom. This results in a non-optimal order for VoiceOver users.

How can I change the order in which VoiceOver reads the NSTextField's within each NSTableCellView?

All examples and documentation I saw about re-ordering VoiceOver elements is related to iOS, but unfortunately the API in macOS is still different.

Comment: Have you tried changing the key view loop by setting `nextKeyView` manually? You can connect this setting in Interface Builder, too.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. Probably because the NSTextField's are readonly.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which an element's accessibility children get visited can be controlled via [`accessibilityChildrenInNavigationOrder()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibilityprotocol/2870186-accessibilitychildreninnavigatio). There are three wrinkles:

1. The children need to match what the view itself is reporting as its `accessibilityChildren`. So for controls, *this will be the control's cell.*
2. The view for which the children are being reordered *must be an `accessibilityElement`*.
3. The method expects *all of the children* which you want to visit to be passed to it. If you leave any out, they will not be visited, and will effectively be hidden from VoiceOver.

So, if you have 4 fields which VO is reading in the order `labelC`, `labelB`, `labelD`, `labelA` but you want in a different order, you can use it like this in **Swift 5**:

```swift
let orderedFields = [labelA, labelB, labelC, labelD]
let orderedChildren = orderedFields.compactMap { $0?.cell }

view.setAccessibilityChildrenInNavigationOrder(orderedChildren)
view.setAccessibilityElement(true)
```

This quickly becomes unwieldy for views with lots of children, but in your case it should work. If you want to do this dynamically, and all of your children are `NSControl`s with cells, you can use `NSCell`'s `tag` property to sort the cells:

```swift
let children = view.accessibilityChildren() as! [NSCell]
let orderedChildren = children.sorted { $0.tag < $1.tag }
        
view.setAccessibilityChildrenInNavigationOrder(orderedChildren as [NSAccessibilityElementProtocol])
view.setAccessibilityElement(true)
```

Then just set the cell tags in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this with code formatted like `cellView.setAccessibilityChildrenInNavigationOrder([cellView.subView1, cellView.subView2, cellView.subView3])` directly after creating the cell view, where 'subView1' is a `NSTextField` control connected to the 'cellView' with an IBOutlet, but unfortunately that didn't work. VoiceOver still reads the controls in the displayed order.

Comment: Let me know if my revised answer solves your problem.